# String adding more than needed to ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to split the words in a string and add it to an array list.Here is the code:

```
String[] textDelimit = fullNameOfProduct.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < textDelimit.length; i++){
    //removes all symbols to check for dictionary match
    textDelimit[i] = textDelimit[i].replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", "");
    System.out.print(textDelimit[i] + " ~ ");
    //Adds cleaned word to list
    productTitleWords.add(textDelimit[i]);
}
System.out.println();
//Prints all cleaned words
for(int i = 0; i < productTitleWords.size(); i++){
    System.out.print(productTitleWords.get(i) + " ");
}
```

This is the original String

`WD Blue 1TB SATA 6 Gb/s 7200 RPM 64MB Cache 3.5 Inch Desktop Hard Drive (WD10EZEX)`

And here is what is printed out for textDelimit:

`WD ~ Blue ~ 1TB ~ SATA ~ 6 ~ Gbs ~ 7200 ~ RPM ~ 64MB ~ Cache ~ 35 ~ Inch ~ Desktop ~ Hard ~ Drive ~ WD10EZEX ~`

And here is what is printed out of productTitleWords

`WD Blue 1TB SATA 6 Gbs 7200 RPM 64MB Cache 35 Inch Desktop Hard Drive WD10EZEX Hard Blue Drive Inch 7200 Blue Hard Blue Hard Drive Cache Drive Inch Blue Inch Blue Hard Hard Blue Drive Inch 7200 Blue Hard Blue Hard Drive Cache Drive Inch Blue Inch Blue Hard`

I need what is in the second printline statement to be inside the productTitleWords arrayList but when printing out that arrayList you get the third print statement. Please help!

Comment: There must be something else going on, because your program produces exactly the output that you expect ([demo](http://ideone.com/AHrMVA)). Voting to close as unable to reproduce.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this is the only method and only class in the whole project except the main method. And you can see all the code

Comment: I second dasblinkenlight's comment. This produces the correct output: `WD Blue 1TB SATA 6 Gbs 7200 RPM 64MB Cache 35 Inch Desktop Hard Drive WD10EZEX`

Comment: This is my result too: `WD ~ Blue ~ 1TB ~ SATA ~ 6 ~ Gbs ~ 7200 ~ RPM ~ 64MB ~ Cache ~ 35 ~ Inch ~ Desktop ~ Hard ~ Drive ~ WD10EZEX ~` 
`WD Blue 1TB SATA 6 Gbs 7200 RPM 64MB Cache 35 Inch Desktop Hard Drive WD10EZEX `

Comment: @Luke Please click the "demo" link above. I copy-pasted your code and your data. If your program is doing it differently, please click "fork" on ideone, edit as required, run, and share the link in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forgot to clear the `productTitleWords` before running the method ?